# public web server getting data from private server

Tags: php, ajax

I have a web server that has 2 interfaces.  1 public and 1 private.

the private interface is on a network with a server that i will be querying.

I am using ajax to fire off a script getGraph.php to pull the image of the graph.
This works fine if i am using a pc that is on the private network(VPN).  Any other pc on any other network fails(times out).  My guess is because ajax is starting the request, so the request comes from my pc, and not from the webserver.  is that true?

```
 $('.menu,.menu2').click(function(){
                            var action = $(this).attr('id')

                            $.ajax({
                                    type:"POST",
                                    url:'getGraph.php',
                                    data:"id="+action,
                                    success: function(result){
                                            $('#data').html(result);
                                    }
```

getGraph.php

```
echo "<img src='https://somePrivateAddress/getImage.php?id=" . $_POST['id'] . ">";
```

if that is the case. How can i use a jquery accordion menu to initiate the queries?

Comment: You will need to use a server side script to call the private server, since javascript is client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`base64_encode()` can be used to "pull the image and print it". Like so:

```
$type = pathinfo($url, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$data = file_get_contents($url);
$base64 = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);
echo '<img src="' . $base64 . '>';
```

You will probably have to re-work this example to fit your needs, since I don't know what you have in the `getImage.php`.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct.  AJAX is entirely executed on the clientside (along with all other javascript).  You will need a tunnel to your private webserver via a public interface.

Comment: Or use PHP to pull the image and print it.

Comment: thats what i assumed getGraph.php did.  ajax calls getGraph, getGraph pulls image from server and echos it.  ajax prints the response....

Comment: You are correct, but you're just echoing back a URL that is unreachable via getGraph.php.  You would need to get the contents of that URL and then echo that back to do what you want.

Comment: how can i "use PHP to pull the image and print it." ?  file_get_contents?

Comment: If you're looking for something simple, $contents = file_get_contents($someurl); echo $contents;